# Google Sheets CountIFS(range, "*string*") but getting exact string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Looking for a way to count cells in a range CONTAINING the word "Transgender" but while ignoring cells that only contain the word "Transgender Man" or "Transgender Women". Cells CAN contain "Transgender" and "Transgender Man" separated by commas and that's worth still counting. But if a cell contains "Transgender Man" but NOT "Transgender" then that needs to be ignored. If a cell only says "Transgender" and does not contain "Transgender Man" then that needs to be counted.

The problem is that my formula:

```
countIFS($P$3:$P, "*Transgender*")
```

also counts cells that only contain "Transgender Man" or "Transgender Woman" when I don't want it to.

Comment: @JvdV I just edited the tags to be only Google Sheets. My apologies.

Comment: @derpirscher I am aware that "Transgender" is inside "Transgender Man". So obviously the logic in the formula is technically correct. But my question is: Is there a formula or other way that can count it the way I described in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach could be to use `QUERY()`, something like:

```
=Query(P3:P,"Select Count(P) where P matches '(?:^|.*,\s*)Transgender(?:\s*,.*|$)' label count(P) ''")
```

Comment: Tested and verified. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What possibly could work -- but with the price of quite an overhead -- is something like the following

```
COUNTIFS(range, "*transgender*") - COUNTIFS(range, "transgender man") - COUNTIFS(range, "transgender woman")
```

Ie, counting all cells that somehow contain the word "transgender" and then substracting all cells which contain exactly "transgender man" or "transgender woman" and nothing else.